Bound an error of a matrix sequence given eigenvalues and eigenvectors basis.
Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ such that $$|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>|\lambda_3|\geq\cdots\geq|\lambda_n|$$ and its eigenvectors $v^{(1)},v^{(2)},\ldots,v^{(n)}$ are linearly independent.
If we start with $x^{(0)}\not\in\text{span}\left(v^{(2)},\ldots,v^{(n)}\right)$, we define $x^{(k+1)}=Ax^{(k)}$. I managed to show that $$R_k=\dfrac{x^{(k+1)}\cdot x^{(k)}}{||x^{(k)}||_2^2}$$ ($\cdot$ denotes usual inner product and subscript 2 the 2-norm for vectors), converges to $\lambda_1$. I achieved it using the fact that $x^{(0)}$ can be written in terms of the eigenvectors basis and $\lambda_j/\lambda_1<1$ for $j\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$.
I want to check if there exists $C>0$ constant that does not depend on $k$ such that $$|R_k-\lambda_1|\leq C\left|\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^k.$$
What I've tried so far is writing $x^{(k+1)}$ and $x^{(k)}$ in terms of the basis and using the fact we are dealing with eigenvectors, and a lot of algebraic manipulation such as factoring out quotients $\left(\dfrac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)$, $\left(\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)$, and factoring out $\lambda_1^k$...however, it led me to nothing, and I think it's not worthy to post it here, if you need it I can link a screenshot of the work, but it kinda turned into a mess. I'm sure there is a better way to prove this without tons of computing.
There is a related question but it is the case of a symmetrix matrix, and with a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors this might be simpler.

$R_k \in \mathcal{O}\left(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^k\right)$ is proved in section 7.3.1 of Golub and Van Loan using estimates of eigenvalues of perturbed matrices. I am not sure if there is a more elementary proof.

Thank you @whpowell96, but it says "it is also easy to verify" haha, still unlucky.

More details are given on the next page with reference to the specific perturbation estimates they use. At least that's how it is in my edition

Yes, I've read a bit, but I'm sure this can be solved in a more elementary way. However, it was useful for some ideas, thank you!
